# Atlassian JavaScript load error We tried to load scripts but something went wrong

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

We tried to load scripts but something went wrong.

Please make sure that your network settings allow you to download scripts from the following domain:

https://aid-frontend.prod.atl-paas.net/atlassian-id/front-end/4.5.0

Tried Google Chrome, Firefox, Internet explorer also tried with different PC.

Not able to login into bitbucket

Comment: In Mozila firefox got this type of error.

Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).

(Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Chrome Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit). I got the same error trying to log in to my group's Atlassian site, and I was able to fix it by specifically allowing JavaScript from Atlassian:

1. Open Chrome settings
2. Click on Advanced
3. Click on Privacy and Security
4. Click on Site Settings
5. Click on JavaScript
6. Make sure JavaScript is set to allowed
7. Next to Allow, click Add
8. Paste the URL from the error message in and click Add

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem recently while traveling and trying to work from a new location.

First I've tried the steps from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58509399/3137698) which unfortunately didn't help  me (but they definitely may be useful in a different case scenario).

I'm renting a house with an existing pre-configured WIFI router which I could get an access to manage it over the web UI.

I'm not sure which of the following helped me. I did the following changes to the router configuration:

1. Added the `8.8.8.8` as a primary DNS Server
2. Enabled IPV6
3. Disabled the built-in firewall (this one is the more likely one which fixed the issue)